# MySQL Start Server 'Can't connect to MySQLServer'

Tags: windows, iis-7, mysql-workbench

I am trying to move database from C to D drive following instructions here:
[Moving and Backing Up a Large MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273621/moving-and-backing-up-a-large-mysql-database)

I copied the data files to the new location (data files are now in both locations) stopped the server then modify the my.ini from: datadir=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data to: datadir=D:\MySQL\data then start the server, I get the below:

```
2014-11-24 10:02:24 - Starting server...
2014-11-24 10:02:24 - Server start done.
2014-11-24 10:02:25 - Checking server status...
2014-11-24 10:02:25 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2014-11-24 10:02:25 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)
```

When I changed back the datadir path back to original it starts up again.

Any suggestions, what am I missing here? Thanks for help!

Cp

Answer (score 0):

After a short walk.. . always good to change setting and come back to it!

The folder did not have NETWORK SERVICE user read/write on that folder. Adding user to the folder and setting read/write fixed the problem.

Hope this helps someone else!